# I'd never thought/I never thought

Tags: grammar, tense

Let's say you are on a journey to your friend's house. Then before you get there, you come across a **dead-end street**, which you never thought of, finally, you and your friend meet. Then you say:

> ''Oh finally I got here!, there was a dead-end street I came across before I got here, and **I'd never thought** there will be one.''

Or

> ''Oh finally I got here!, there was a dead-end street I came across before I got here, and **I never thought** there will be one.''

Which is correct?

Comment: You are on a journey, not your. I think it would be better to say "I never knew there was a dead-end street there".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, neither of your example sentences are correct. Not because of "I'd never" versus "I never" but because of a few other issues—most notably "there will be one."

They can be rephrased in a couple of ways. (I will also simplify to focus on the essential elements.)

- "Oh, I finally got here! I came across a dead-end street **I had never thought was** there."
- "Oh, I finally got here! I came across a dead-end street **I never thought would be** there."

Depending on what you change *will be* to will determine which of the two you would use.

Comment: Can I say: "Oh, I finally got here! I came across a dead-end street I had never thought was there **before** I reached this place.

Comment: Yes that's grammatically correct. However, it's slightly awkward. I had to stop and reread the sentence before I realized that you were using "[before] I reached this place" instead of "I had never thought was there [before]." Because of how it's read, you first assume that "before" goes at the end of he previous part of the sentence. But it's technically correct, and only slightly awkward.

Comment: A change that avoids any confusion at all: "Oh, I finally got here! Before I reached this place, I came across a dead-end street I had never thought was there."